# iOS framework for developing rich graphic applications

Tags: ios, core-animation

Let's say I wanted to develop interface like in Smule (iPhone flute app).
[Youtube linke to Smule](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RhCJq7EAJJA)

What sort of Frameworks I should consider using. Should I stick to native frameworks in iOS such as CoreAnimation, OpenGL ES or, are there any third party framework which makes job easier ?

thanks.
Waruna.

Comment: This question seems very open ended, it really depends on what you're looking to accomplish or trying to learn.

Comment: For such a simple animation (the one in the video), CoreAnimation is more than enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends on so many parameters... there are so many options...

Just some questions to get you started:

- What are your skills? (Comfortable with OpenGL? What about Objective-C?)
- What is your budget? (Money for proprietary frameworks? Time to do low level stuff?)
- Is performance an issue? (For smule apparently it is not.)

With a scripting framework like [Pythonista](http://omz-software.com/pythonista/) this could probably be achieved in half a day and under a hundred lines of code with decent performance... if it would support input from the mic...

Comment: Hi, I'm quite comfortable with objective- c, c++ and c. But haven't done much programming with openGL. Actually you could say nothing. Time frame is about 4 months, I could use purchase a commercial proprietary framework, if I could justify it is worth the money. Yes performance is a issue, so I'm not sure framework like Pythonista works here.

Comment: I'd put this info into your main question. Is quite relevant to someone trying to help you. Pythonista has its limits, but could be worth the test, especially the Particles and the Piano demos. 1 month should be plenty to get you started with python. If you'd be comfortable with C# and graphics performance is the big issue, I'd recommend Unity. Depends also on the graphics effects you desire to achieve. Can you do it with images and changing alpha, rotation and dimensions (in which case CoreAnimation is sufficient) or do you want to do more elaborate renderings?